# Notepad++ Merge 2 lines into 1 line

Tags: notepad++, editing

I have the following text;

> country=france
>   name=jean 
>   country=germany 
>   name=michael 
>   country=england
>   name=jack

I want it to look like;

> country=france name=jean 
>  country=germany name=michael 
>   country=england name=jack

How do I do this in Notepad++?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the extended replace functionality and replace "\r\nname" with " name"

Substitute appropriate line ending characters for \r\n depending on the file.

If it is from windows, use \r\n

If it is from unix, use \n

If it is from mac, use \r

Comment: @Sarah Meadow You may also see http://superuser.com/questions/411193/append-lines-one-after-another-in-notepad

Answer (score 28):

Choose Edit → Line Operations → Join Lines from the menu or

Select the lines & press Ctrl + J --> Easiest option  :)

Comment: On small structures, manual method is often quicker and more effective than elaborated (programmatic) one. Specifically because very often such structures would have some value that would typically astray from the rule that intends to cover it. Having a chance to overlook values adds significance. However, for most of programmers, a programmatic solution is [sadly] more appealing and would be rather utilized even if that turns to be a situation of killing the mosquito with a cannon.

Comment: And CTRL-J is remarkably like the vim "J" command. Nicely, you don't even have to have the entire lines selected, just portions.

Comment: How is that any faster than pressing `END` then `DELETE`? You could get into a rhythm just pressing `END`, `DEL`, `DOWN` over and over. To @ljgww'spoint, it would take you weeks to kill a lot of mosquitoes using `Join Lines` or using this way, which is why programmers prefer the cannon, because we're often working with thousands of lines at a time.

Comment: @pbarney you're right, but there are a few ways Ctrl-J may be more efficient: (a) interleaves spaces if necessary, (b) collapses multiple lines at once, (c) possibly more hands-free (mouse with right hand, Ctrl-J with left) but unsure about that one.

Answer (score 5):

1. Open "Search>Replace" dialog
2. In the "Find What" field place the string "(country=\w*)\r\n(name=\w*)" without quotes.
3. In the "Replace With" field palce the string "(\1) (\2)", also without quotes.
4. Mark the "Regular Expression" Search Mode.
5. Press "Find Next" to test it.
6. If 2 lines starting with country=XX and name=YY are selected, then press "Replace All".

If you're not using windows, you'll have to use only \n or \r, depending if you're using linux/unix or mac.

[Notepad++ Uses Posix Regular](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/searching/normal-search) expressions. You can refer to any standard Posix Regex reference, like [this one](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm) or [this one](http://krijnhoetmer.nl/stuff/regex/cheat-sheet/).

Answer (score -1):

Want to add in case it can help with similar case:
to replace lines in file when previous line digit and second text

```
1
text
2
text
```

based on [Filipe Fedalto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/959251/filipe-fedalto) answer regex will be:

```
find:(\d+)\r\n
replace:(\1)
```

Comment: How is this answering the question?

Comment: Its direct answer of question of topic:
"Notepad++ Merge 2 lines into 1 line"
I cannot find needed information and found similar question, so my answer could help in similar situation, whats wrong?

Comment: This doesn't answer the specific question and this is not a generic answer.

Comment: So, nothing similar?