# notepad++ line combine

Tags: regex, notepad++

We have this line order

```
129
12
2020
5424180606943758
```

we need to be this way

```
5424180606943758|12|2020|129
```

how to do this in notepad ++ or in onoter app

Comment: What did you try yourself? did you try if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11084086/notepad-merge-2-lines-into-1-line) solves your problem? and, if not, why?

Comment: is there any specific ordering requirement here or we just need to make all records into a single row with record delimiter as pipe(|)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(\d+)\R(\d+)\R(\d+)\R(\d+)\R?`
- Replace with: `$4|$3|$2|$1`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(\d+)           # group 1, 1 or more digits
\R              # any kind of linebreak
(\d+)           # group 2, 1 or more digits
\R              # any kind of linebreak
(\d+)           # group 3, 1 or more digits
\R              # any kind of linebreak
(\d+)           # group 4, 1 or more digits
\R              # any kind of linebreak, optional
```

**Replacement:**

```
$4          # content of group 4
|           # a pipe
$3          # content of group 3
|           # a pipe
$2          # content of group 2
|           # a pipe
$1          # content of group 1
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]